# Scraping titles and subtitles from different pages

Tags: web-scraping

I'm a student and attending university lessons from home. My teacher just gave me this job, consisting to take all the titles and subtitles from an online italian journal that include the words "coronavirus" and / or "covid 19" in a certain time lapse (from 22th to 29th of January and just the 1st and the 8th of April), and transcribe them to an Excel file to analyze the words used.

I searched online and assumed that this could be considered scraping, and that made my day considering that I should find something like 100-150 titles plus subtitles and I have a very short deadline. Unfortunately, I am also a beginner at this and all I could do by myself was finding a way to collect just the title from the webpage. I'm using, like a beginner is supposed to, Data Miner with Google Chrome.

Practically I should find all titles and subtitles from the website "La Gazzetta dello Sport" (whose link I attach below) that contains the words "coronavirus" and/or "covid 19" but there is a problem: I can see just the titles in the search page, but to get the subtitles I should click on the article and go to another page. Is there a way to obtain all the results with Data Miner or should I use another program?

So, just to make it simple: I can't figure out how to make Data Miner collect the title from the search page, click it to go on the article page, collect the subtitle and go back to the search page to pass to the next title and subtitle and repeat. I don't know if this is possible or it's just sci-fi, like I said: I'm a total newbie at this and it's the first time using these kind of tools.

Url: https://www.gazzetta.it/nuovaricerca/home.shtml?q=coronavirus&dateFrom=2020-01-22&dateTo=2020-01-29

Comment: Readers will find it really helpful to see what work you have done so far, so that anything they suggest is compatible with what you already have. I am not familiar with Data Miner, but could you show what config/code you have?

Comment: I imagine also that your teacher would be happy to give you guidance as to what tools to use, unless tool selection is part of the challenge. You don't want to be using a GUI system, for example, if your teacher wanted you to write some programming code.

Comment: I can't write here what code I have used to obtain the titles of the page because Data Miner is an extension of Chrome and it basically detects via clicking the elements or cluster in the page and then extrapulate the data you need. Practically I don't have a code! The program calls it "recipe" and does it automatically, but I put here a link if you are interested in more. 
My teacher is been quite generical about it, asking me simply to do it. I'm not studying Informatics but the task is to collect words and to do it I was thinking about web scraping. I'm open to any suggest!

Comment: Here is the link -> (https://data-miner.io/how-it-works)

Comment: They have [paid support options here](https://data-miner.io/assistance), which may be of use. I can't help, but I imagine that where someone knows this technology, they will need some more guidance from you as to what you are stuck on. At present they will read this and say, OK, someone is asking for a few hours work. Occasionally that does happen here, but most of the time, volunteers think of that as asking for too much.

Comment: I don't know, would taking some screenshots of the control panel clarify the problem for readers?